# White Status bar when pushing TTPhotoViewController using [self.navigationController pushViewController:]

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, three20, pushviewcontroller, ttphotoviewcontroller, uistatusbar

I'm pushing `myPhotoviewcontroller` when `TTThumbview` is selected.
where `myPhotoviewcontroller` is inherited from `TTPhotoViewController`.

```
- (void)thumbsViewController: (TTThumbsViewController*)controller
              didSelectPhoto: (id<TTPhoto>)photo;
{   

    [myPhotoViewController setCenterPhoto:photo];
    [self.managingViewController.navigationController pushViewController:myPhotoViewController animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"Thumb view tapped...");
}
```

It is pushed fine. But when the navigation bar is toggled on single click then status bar is turned to white color.

The `PhotoViewController` displays, with the images and the thumbnails view as-well. Only it seems that the photoview is to high because the bottom bar is not showing and the caption is halfly displayed. Also the when clicking on a photo the top navigation bar and status bar first fade to white and doesn't disappear When clicking on the photo again the status-bar and navigation bar appear without fading and causing the photo to move downwards again.

If anybody knows the correct way of pushing the `TTPhotoViewController` into view without using the Navigator can you please show me how.

Comment: have you found any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Specifying fullScreenLayout did the trick.

```
- (void)thumbsViewController: (TTThumbsViewController*)controller
          didSelectPhoto: (id<TTPhoto>)photo;
{   

    [myPhotoViewController setCenterPhoto:photo];
    myPhotoViewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    [self.managingViewController.navigationController pushViewController:myPhotoViewController animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"Thumb view tapped...");
}
```